# GADT Type Inference with Higher-Kinded Types

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've got some code that compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, KindSignatures, GADTs, 
             FlexibleContexts #-}

module Foo where

data Foo :: (* -> *) where
  Foo :: c m zp' -> Foo (c m zp)

f :: forall c m zp d . Foo (c m zp) -> d
f y@(Foo (x :: c m a)) = g x y

g :: c m a -> Foo (c m b) -> d
g = error ""
```

The key thing I need in my real code is to convince GHC that if `y` has the type `Foo (c m zp)` and `x` has the type `c' m' zp'`, then `c' ~ c` and `m' ~ m`. The above code achieves this because I am able to call `g`.

I want to change this code in two orthogonal ways, but I can't seem to figure out how to make GHC compile the code with either change.

First change: Add `-XPolyKinds`. GHC 7.8.3 complains:

```
Foo.hs:10:11:
    Could not deduce ((~) (k2 -> k3 -> *) c1 c)
    from the context ((~) * (c m zp) (c1 m1 zp1))
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 Foo :: forall (k :: BOX)
                               (k :: BOX)
                               (c :: k -> k -> *)
                               (m :: k)
                               (zp' :: k)
                               (zp :: k).
                        c m zp' -> Foo (c m zp),
               in an equation for ‘f’
      at Foo.hs:10:6-21
      ‘c1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           a pattern with constructor
             Foo :: forall (k :: BOX)
                           (k :: BOX)
                           (c :: k -> k -> *)
                           (m :: k)
                           (zp' :: k)
                           (zp :: k).
                    c m zp' -> Foo (c m zp),
           in an equation for ‘f’
           at Foo.hs:10:6
      ‘c’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for f :: Foo (c m zp) -> d
          at Foo.hs:9:13
    Expected type: c1 m1 zp'
      Actual type: c m a
    Relevant bindings include
      y :: Foo (c m zp) (bound at Foo.hs:10:3)
      f :: Foo (c m zp) -> d (bound at Foo.hs:10:1)
    In the pattern: x :: c m a
    In the pattern: Foo (x :: c m a)
    In an equation for ‘f’: f y@(Foo (x :: c m a)) = g x y

Foo.hs:10:11:
    Could not deduce ((~) k2 m1 m)
    from the context ((~) * (c m zp) (c1 m1 zp1))
    ...
```

Second change: Forget about `-XPolyKinds`. Instead I want to use `-XDataKinds` to create a new kind and restrict the kind of `m`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, KindSignatures, GADTs, 
             FlexibleContexts, DataKinds #-}

module Foo where

data Bar

data Foo :: (* -> *) where
  Foo :: c (m :: Bar) zp' -> Foo (c m zp)

f :: forall c m zp d . Foo (c m zp) -> d
f y@(Foo (x :: c m a)) = g x y

g :: c m a -> Foo (c m b) -> d
g = error ""
```

I get similar errors (`can't deduce (c1 ~ c)`, `can't deduce (m1 ~ m)`).
`DataKinds` seems to be relevant here: if I restrict `m` to have kind `Constraint` instead of kind `Bar`, the code compiles fine.

---

I've given two examples of how to break the original code, both of which use higher-kinded types. I've tried using case statements instead of pattern guards, I've tried giving a type to `node` instead of `x`, my usual tricks aren't working here.

I'm not picky about where the type for `x` ends up/what it looks like, I just need to be able to convince GHC that if `y` has the type `Foo (c m zp)`, then `x` has the type `c m zp'` for some unrelated type `zp'`.

Comment: In the type signatures you give for `x` and `y`, `zp` and `zp'` are completely unrelated types. You have mentioned `zp` in the type signature of the function, but `zp'` is mentioned nowhere else. How can you expect the compiler to infer some relation between them?

Comment: @user2407038 I don't. I just want the `c` and `m` to be the same.

Comment: The stub for `g` doesn't work in `f` with the provided type. It does work in `f` with `g :: ASTF dom (c m a) -> ASTF dom (c m b) -> ASTF dom (c m b)`. The type of `g` is suspiciously similar to the type of `f`; it doesn't convince me that there are any interesting functions that require this proof.

Comment: I've asked a [(hopefully) related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990891/does-type-equality-imply-kind-equality) about type equality implying kind equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I greatly simplified the original question to the following, which compiles without `{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}` but fails to compile with `PolyKinds`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, KindSignatures, GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}

data Pair1 :: (* -> *) where
  Pair1 :: Pair1 (c a, c b)

data D p a where
    D :: p (a, b) -> D p a -> D p b

f :: forall c z. D Pair1 (c z) -> D Pair1 (c z)
f y@(D Pair1 x) |
    (_ :: D Pair1 (c z)) <- y,
    (_ :: D Pair1 (c z')) <- x = y
```

With `PolyKinds` enabled the compiler error is

```
Could not deduce (c1 ~ c)
from the context ((a, c z) ~ (c1 a1, c1 b))
```

This error strongly suggests what I already suspected, that an answer depends on whether [polykinded type application is injective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990891/does-type-equality-imply-kind-equality). If polykinded type application were injective, we could deduce `c1 ~ c` as follows.

```
(a,   c z) ~ (c1 a1,   c1 b)
(a,) (c z) ~ (c1 a1,) (c1 b) {- switch to prefix notation -}
      c z  ~           c1 b  {- f a ~ g b implies a ~ b -}
      c    ~           c1    {- f a ~ g b implies f ~ g -}
      c1   ~           c     {- ~ is reflexive -}
```

[Polykinded type application is injective](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993048/414413), but ghc doesn't know it. In order for ghc to deduce that the type application is injective, we need to provide kind signatures so that the compiler is aware the kinds are equivalent.

I haven't found sufficient kind annotations for your original, over-simplified version of the problem. When simplifying problems juggling types, reducing a type to essentially a `Proxy` is sometimes excessive, as it leaves fewer places to attach type signatures. You have [found places to attach kind signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993521/414413) to a more meaningful problem.

Comment: No, the type of `x` isn't necessary to write the toy code I gave, but it is necessary to write the code I actually want. I added stub for a function `g`, hopefully that addresses your question.

Comment: "Those are exactly what it claims it can't deduce..." Not quite. If you change `discard` to return a proxy for `x`, *then* it is the same. Your code matches the types of `y` with itself. I'm trying to match the types in `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be resolved by adding *kind signatures*.

For example, when using `-XPolyKinds`, the following code compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, KindSignatures, GADTs, 
             FlexibleContexts, PolyKinds #-}

module Foo where

data Foo :: (* -> *) where
  Foo :: (c :: k -> * -> *) m zp' -> Foo (c m zp)

f :: forall (c :: k -> * -> *) m zp d . Foo (c m zp) -> d
f y@(Foo x) = g x y

g :: c m a -> Foo (c m b) -> d
g = error ""
```

For the `-XDataKinds` version, I also need a kind signature on `g`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, KindSignatures, GADTs, 
             FlexibleContexts, DataKinds #-}

module Foo where

data Bar

data Foo :: (* -> *) where
  Foo :: (c :: Bar -> * -> *) m zp' -> Foo (c m zp)

f :: forall (c :: Bar -> * -> *) m zp d . Foo (c m zp) -> d
f y@(Foo x) = g x y

g :: forall (c :: Bar -> * -> *) m a b d . c m a -> Foo (c m b) -> d
g = error ""
```

Not sure why I need more sigs for `DataKinds`, and it's a bit annoying to have to copy them everywhere, but it does get the job done.