# Is polykinded type application injective?

Tags: haskell, higher-kinded-types, type-kinds, polykinds

#### Is polykinded type application injective?

When we [enable `PolyKinds`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism.html), do we know that `f a ~ g b` implies `f ~ g` and `a ~ b`?

#### Motivation

When [trying to answer another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27978248/414413), I reduced the problem to the point that I received the following error only with `PolyKinds` enabled.

```
Could not deduce (c1 ~ c)
from the context ((a, c z) ~ (c1 a1, c1 b))
```

If polykinded type application were injective, we could deduce `c1 ~ c` as follows.

```
(a,   c z) ~ (c1 a1,   c1 b)
(a,) (c z) ~ (c1 a1,) (c1 b) {- switch to prefix notation -}
      c z  ~           c1 b  {- f a ~ g b implies a ~ b -}
      c    ~           c1    {- f a ~ g b implies f ~ g -}
      c1   ~           c     {- ~ is reflexive -}
```

#### Type application is injective

In Haskell, type application is injective. If `f a ~ g b` then `f ~ g` and `a ~ b`. We can prove this to ourselves by compiling the following

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Control.Applicative

second :: a -> a -> a
second _ = id

typeApplicationIsInjective :: (Applicative f, f a ~ g b) => f a -> g b -> f b
typeApplicationIsInjective fa gb = second <$> fa <*> gb
```

#### Kind of type application is not injective

The kind of a type application is not injective. If we consider the following, which has kind `(* -> *) -> *`.

```
newtype HoldingInt f = HoldingInt (f Int)
```

We can ask ghci what kind something of kind `(* -> *) -> *` has when applied to something of kind `* -> *`, which is `*`

```
> :k HoldingInt
HoldingInt :: (* -> *) -> *
> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
> :k HoldingInt Maybe
HoldingInt Maybe :: *
```

This is the same kind as something of kind `* -> *` applied to something of kind `*`

```
> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
> :k Int
Int :: *
> :k Maybe Int
Maybe Int :: *
```

Therefore, it is not true that, borrowing [syntax from `KindSignatures`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html), the first set of kind signatures implies anything in the second.

```
f :: kf, g :: kg, a :: ka, b :: kb, f a :: k, g b :: k
g :: kf, f :: kg, b :: ka, a :: kb
```

Comment: `HoldingInt Maybe` is something of kind `(* -> *) -> *` applied to *something of* kind `* -> *`. To apply something to a kind, it would need to have sort `Kind -> ...`.

Comment: @TwanvanLaarhoven I've sprinkled in more *something of*s.

Comment: I think there must be a typo in your second sentence since `ord 'a' ~ (+1) 1` but `ord !~ (+1)` and `'a' !~ 1`. Does `~` not mean "has the same type as"?

Comment: @genisage `~` means "*is* the same type as". It operates on types not on values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polykinded type application is injective from the outside, but certainly not injective from inside Haskell.

By "injective from the outside" I mean that whenever there is a `Refl` with type `f a :~: g b`, then it must be the case that `f` is equal to `g` and `a` is equal to `b`, and since we know that types of different kinds are never equal, the kinds must be also the same.

The issue is that GHC only has homogeneous type equality constraints, and doesn't have kind equality constraints at all. The machinery for encoding GADTs using coercions exists only on the type and promoted type level. That's why we can't express heterogeneous equality, and why we can't promote GADTs.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds, GADTs, TypeOperators #-}

data HEq (a :: i) (b :: k) :: * where
  HRefl :: HEq a a
-- ERROR: Data constructor ‘HRefl’ cannot be GADT-like in its *kind* arguments
```

Also, here's a simple example of GHC not inferring injectivity:

```
sym1 :: forall f g a b. f a :~: g b -> g b :~: f a
sym1 Refl = Refl
-- ERROR: could not deduce (g ~ f), could not deduce (b ~ a)
```

If we annotate `a` and `b` with the same kind, it checks out.

[This paper](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~justhsu/docs/nokinds.pdf) talks about the above limitations and how they could be eliminated in GHC (they describe a system with unified kind/type coercions and heterogeneous equality constraints).

Answer (score 5):

If a type-level application has different kinds, then the two types can not be shown to be equal. Here is evidence:

```
GHC.Prim> () :: ((Any :: * -> *) Any) ~ ((Any :: (* -> *) -> *) Any) => ()
<interactive>:6:1:
    Couldn't match kind ‘*’ with ‘* -> *’
    Expected type: Any Any
      Actual type: Any Any
    In the expression:
        () :: ((Any :: * -> *) Any) ~ ((Any :: (* -> *) -> *) Any) => ()
    In an equation for ‘it’:
        it
          = () :: ((Any :: * -> *) Any) ~ ((Any :: (* -> *) -> *) Any) => ()

<interactive>:6:7:
    Couldn't match kind ‘*’ with ‘* -> *’
    Expected type: Any Any
      Actual type: Any Any
    In the ambiguity check for: Any Any ~ Any Any => ()
    To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
    In an expression type signature:
      ((Any :: * -> *) Any) ~ ((Any :: (* -> *) -> *) Any) => ()
    In the expression:
        () :: ((Any :: * -> *) Any) ~ ((Any :: (* -> *) -> *) Any) => ()
```

(Even turning on the suggested `AllowAmbiguousTypes` extension gives the same type-checking error -- just without the suggestion.)

Therefore, if two types can be shown to be equal, then type-level applications in the same structural position on the two sides of the equality have the same kind.

If you wish for proof instead of evidence, one would need to write down a careful inductive proof about the system described in [Type Checking with Open Type Functions](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/papers/tc-tfs.pdf). Inspection of Figure 3 suggests to me that the invariant, "all type applications in ~'s have the same kind on both sides of the ~" is preserved, though neither I nor the paper prove this carefully, so there is some chance it is not so.

Comment: I wonder if type application is only injective for kinds constructed from `*` and `(->)`. Type application may not be injective for kinds constructed from the other kind that is floating around, `GHC.Exts.Constraint`, or for any future kind in general.

Comment: `Constraint` is no issue by itself. We run into problems precisely when there should be an `a ~ b` constraint where `a` and `b` have different kinds (because such constraints are unrepresentable in GHC).